# Samsung Galaxy Tab GT-P1000 USB Cable Problems ; Charging Problems

Tags: usb, root-access, charging, samsung-galaxy-tab

Galaxy Tab is an old tablet.Yesterday,I can "resurrect" it from the dead,and I buy a fake USB cable to charge and exchange data.
Since I have a worser phone than the Galaxy Tab,I really want to play my games there (Galaxy Tab.)

However,it requires us to have a minimum of 2.3 (Gingerbread) and above to play the game.
Somebody suggested me root the device and use the latest 4.4 OS,since they say it can improve the performance of the tab.

I tried to root the device,first using Z4Root app (APK).It doesn't works.(Took 3 hour and no result,tried everything.)

Then,I tried to connect it to a PC.I've downloaded the Kies but it doesn't work.I tried installing the USB drivers,but still,my PC (and Kies) can't detect it.

And also,when I tried charging it,sometimes the tab recognize the tablet as connecting to a pc,not charging.Alhough so,sometimes it works,so yeah.

You guys have any solution?

Answer (score 1):

The fact that your Tab is not being recognized by the PC is telling me that there could be an issue with the USB drivers.  Try uninstalling all Samsung USB drivers (including the Kies utility) and then re-installing Kies from [here](http://www.samsung.com/ca/support/usefulsoftware/KIES/JSP).

Further, if you want to only root the tab, follow the steps outlined in [this thread](http://forum.xda-developers.com/showthread.php?t=812367):

> Prerequisites:
>
> 1) Kies Software downloaded from [HERE](http://www.samsung.com/ca/support/usefulsoftware/KIES/JSP) and installed, and Tab connected even once
>   2) USB debugging enabled
>   3) SuperOnceClick downloaded from [HERE](http://forum.xda-developers.com/showthread.php?t=803682)
>
> Process:
>   1) Connect your galaxy tab with debugging mode disabled and sync with Kies even once
>   2) Disconnect it and enable debugging mode from Settings -> Applications -> Development -> USB Debugging
>   3) Connect the tab again to PC and click on home button so that Tab comes out of Kies connection
>   4) Launch SuperOneClick.exe
>   5) Click on root and wait for 5-10 Mins

If you want to install custom ROMs like CyanogenMod for example, you will need to flash a custom recovery first by following the steps in [this post](http://theunlockr.com/2012/05/07/how-to-root-and-flash-the-clockworkmod-recovery-on-the-galaxy-tab-p1000-running-gingerbread/):

> 1. Download Odin from [here](http://www.mediafire.com/download/a3a7a43u6s3kbwm/Odin3+v1.7.rar) and extract it to a folder on your desktop.
> 2. Download the custom recovery from [here](http://www.mediafire.com/download/q8s0wnj1s6109gc/CF-Root-TAB7_XX_OXA_JQ1-v3.3-CWM3RFS.tar)
> 3. Launch Odin3 v1.7.exe to open the Odin application.
> 4. On Odin, click on PDA.  Navigate to the location where you have downloaded CF-Root-TAB7_XX_OXA_JQ1-v3.3-CWM3RFS.tar to from above and select it.
> 5. This is the most important instruction ever and we really can’t stress how important this is.  **Make sure that the Re-Partition tickbox is unchecked!!  Ticking this is a surefire way to brick your device.**
> 6. Power down your P1000.
> 7. With the device powered down, press and hold the Volume Down + Power buttons until the device boots into Download Mode.
> 8. Connect the device to your Windows PC using a microUSB cable.  Odin should now recognize your device and the ID:COM should light up yellow.
> 9. Click on Start.  **Again, make sure that Re-Partition is unchecked!!**
> 10. Download your favorite ROM (e.g. CyanogenMod).
> 11. Copy the downloaded ROM zip file to the SD card on your device and disconnect the device from your PC.
> 12. Boot into ClockworkMod Recovery.  To do this, with the device powered down, press and hold Volume Up + Power until it boots into Recovery.
> 13. Select "Install zip from SD card".  Navigate to the location where you downloaded the ROM zip, select it and then select "Install".
> 14. Optionally, download and flash the GApps package compatible with your ROM.